# How to erase data from table automatically?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a table

it has four fields :`Phone_number(primary key),City_name,Category_product and sub_Category`

I am develoing a php application such based on an sms gateway.
whenver a user sends and sms requesting a product service,
his details will be saved in this table.

Now when a user sends an SMS ,i will store the details in the table,and
wait for the user to send back an sms with further details as per required.

Now what i want to do is:
if a user does not respond in lets say 15 min his details should be deleted from the table automatically.
How should i proceed?

Comment: instead of deleting the entr, include a new column(`datetime`) and store the date-time values, and compare against it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a column to your table that stores the time it was sent.

Then you have to choices, you can either run cron jobs to clean out the data, or you clean up the records that are not valid when another user sends a sms, etc. Since you store the time with the data you can easily change the timeout from 15 minutes later on, too.

Comment: how can i set a timeout condition? i do not want to run a cron job.
Should i timestamp at the time a record is created? and then compare it later?

Comment: Exactly you would store a timestamp and compare it later (e.g. time()-$time_sent > 900) and if it returns true the record is older than 15 minutes.

Comment: for this i will have to run a php script continuously on the server?
 if suppose i ahve large number of records it will take a lot of time

Comment: No, not necessarily. You could for example run the script every time another SMS is send. If you have a high load on the server you may want to utilize a garbage collection system.

Comment: You could use something similar to this: `if ((time() - $time_sent) >= 900) { deleteOldRecords(); }`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some scheduling. PHP dont have any native support for scheduling. What I would suggest is create a descktop applicaion or a service which listens the table for SMS response. If it did not get response then it will delete the correspond record. Your job will be running infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

If this is going to be a table with many records, you should set up a pre-order table and then copy the record over when the order is made. In this way, you can clean up the pre-order table anytime you want if it starts getting slow.

As Ben said, it should have a timestamp for checks.